# How to truncate f64 to 2 decimal places?

Tags: rust

How to truncate `f64` to 2 decimal places?

From

```
let before = 17.69108280254777;
```

To

```
let after = 17.69;
```

Comment: I think he's not looking for {:.2} or maybe he is.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci, right.
i think it will be easier to understand with the expected result that i want.

Comment: So you just want `println!("{:.2}", before); // prints 17.69`?

Comment: @weiz what you're demonstrating here is rounding, the question is whether you'd also want `17.697` to print as `17.69` (truncation), or whether you want `17.70` (rounding). The formatting system uses the latter, if you need the former you'll have to truncate first, then format.

Comment: @Masklinn really thanks for the explanation , I think its the truncation one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't actually get rounding without rounding, but i think a workaround like this can get the job done

```
fn main() {
    let before = 17.69108280254777;
    let after = f64::trunc(before  * 100.0) / 100.0; // or f32::trunc
}
```

Outputs:

```
17.69
```

Comment: For two decimal places it should be 100 not 1000. And you could use [.floor()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.floor) instead of type conversion for better readability, e.g. `let after = (before * 100f64).floor() / 100.0;`

Comment: No worries. I also made an error. Because it should be [trunc()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.trunc) not floor() for dealing with negative numbers.